# Removing extra white space when exporting map from ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, pdf, layouts

My map elements (map, legend, scale bar, and etc) are within the "Printer Margin", which I have set in the Page and Setup window.

However, when I export my map as a pdf, there is additional white space that is exported. The extra white space is only found at the bottom of the page not the top and the width of the exported map is fine.

How do I ensure that only the map elements within the Printer Margin are only exported without the extra whitespace?

Comment: I think you need to include a picture or pictures that show us the appearance of both the layout and the PDF.

Comment: Do you have any floating elements in the layout that are outside of the layout extent?

Comment: I agree with @artwork21.  You probable have a text element or an empty legend that falls outside the print area but is not visible unless the element is selected.  In the layout view use the selection tool and draw a box around the page.  Look for highlighted (but empty) elements in the area in question.  Select that element and delete it.  Reprint.

Answer (score 2):

1. Are you seeing this on the PDF or do you see this after printing?
2. Do you have a check in the "Clip Output to Graphics Extent"? I usually leave that blank.
   [image: Clip Output to Graphics Extent]

Comment: Sorry I meant to add that as a comment - not an answer. cheers!